# WPF How to use a ComboBoxes selected item as a xctk:PropertyGrid's SelectedObject in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, propertygrid

I have a combo box that contains items of a different type so I can't bind to a list. I have set the items in the xaml individually as there will only ever be two items, so am not worried about the maintenance overheads in this situation. 
 I also have a property grid (from Xceed) and would like to set the selectedObject of it to the selected item of my combo box. I am using the MVVM pattern and can't find a solution where you set the property grids selected object in the xaml. 
 Here is the xaml for the combobox and property grid, there's not much to see, just the declaration of each.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Name="TestComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
    <ComboBoxItem <!-- Set the item binding for item 1 to property in view model-->>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem <!-- Set the item binding for item 2 to property in view model-->>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
<xctk:PropertyGrid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedObject="{Binding <!-- Bind to comboBoxes selected item-->}"/>
```

I'm not sure if this is even possible as I think ComboBox uses a list of objects as it's structure, so it probably isn't going to work, setting items individually as I want.

Comment: could you paste your xaml here please

Comment: in combobox selection changed event, you can give the 
propertygrid.selected object=combobox.selectedItem;

Comment: @Hariprasadkasavajjala That would be in the code behind, I was looking for a way to do it using just the view model and xaml (mvvm)

Comment: assign a value to a view model object when selected item changes, Bind the same object to property grid and call update property changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind the `SelectedObject` property to the currently selected item in the `ComboBox` like this:

```
<xctk:PropertyGrid ... SelectedObject="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=TestComboBox}">
```

You probably don't want to add `ComboBoxItems` to the `ComboBox` in your XAML markup though because then you will be binding to a `ComboBoxItem`, but that's another story.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Seems nicer than creating a selected object property in the view model, then binding to it with the combobox and datagrid. As for the setting of the items, I've changed that, I know use a list and have restructured my classes.